# Count visible elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have a table with a filter. The problem is when the filter prevents the table from showing tr rows, it should display a message saying no rows.

How do I check if the table doesn't have any visible rows? Basically if it's 0 I want to show a message on the table `emptyTable: "There are no test cases of the selected type."`. **I'm using datatable.**

```
function changeTableOnType() {
    var type = $('#type').val();
    if(type !== 'All') {
        $('tbody tr').hide();
        $('.' + type).closest('tr').show();
    }
    else {
        $('tbody tr').show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Use the `:visible` selector: `$('tbody tr:visible').length`

Answer (score 0):

Use [:visible](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector

```
function changeTableOnType() {
    var type = $('#type').val();
    if(type !== 'All') {
        $('tbody tr').hide();
        $('.' + type).closest('tr').show();
    }
    else {
        $('tbody tr').show();
    }

    if($("tbody tr:visible").length===0){
       alert("No rows visible");
       // Or show some html error here
    }

}
```